# How to get the selected tab names in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LTpL6/

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs_down_link">
    <li ><a style="   padding: 7px 14px;font-size: 16px; color: #000; border-   bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;"  href="#view_down7">Subject Area-Based Citations</a></li>
                                                            <li ><a    href="#view_down8">Sub-Area Based Citations</a></li>
      </ul>

 <div class="tabcontents_down_link">
 <div id="view_down7" style="line-height:180%; font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;  color: #808080; ">
                                                                <input   type="checkbox" />&nbsp;(SciCI)<br/>
                                                                <input   type="checkbox" />&nbsp;(SS&HCI)<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp; (M&HSCI) <br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp;(LSciCI)<br/>

 </div>

  <div id="view_down8" style="font-weight: bold;line-height:180%; font-size: 14px; color: #808080;">
                                                                <input    type="checkbox" />&nbsp;History Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Religion Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input   type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Biotechnology Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Food Science Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Chemistry Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Mathematics Citation Index<br/>
                                                                <input  type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Neuroscience Citation Index<br/>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('div[id^=view_down]').hide();
       $('#view_down7').show();
       $('.tabs_down_link a').click(function () {
           var tab_id = $(this).attr('href');
           var now = $(this).attr('.tabs_down_link a');
           $('div[id^=view_down]').hide();
           $(tab_id).show(); 
       });
   });
```

Here everything works fine.

Now there are two tabs 1.Subject Area-Based Citations 2.Sub-Area Based Citations

There is a common div where user click clicks on any the specific tab the content would be shown in that common div, now its showing correctly, but i need the tab names to be be changed according to the clicked tab.

So now the default is Subject Area-Based Citations tab, so when user tries to click on Sub-Area Based Citations then the tab name 'Sub-Area Based Citations' should automatically come to the first default tab.

How to do that please help.

Comment: I'm going to delete the answer... that will be pretty messy as you will have to keep track of previously clicked title and its target and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code to your $('.tabs_down_link a').click() function and it should change the tab names accordingly.

```
var newName =  $(this).text();
    $(this).text($('#selected-tab').text());
   $('#selected-tab').text(newName);
```

This code will inter-change the names of first selected tab and selected tab. Don't forget to give id "selected-tab" to the first tab.

Comment: check out this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVJ46/1/). fork of your project...Guess this is what u wanted?

Comment: Yah correct bro, but now the div part is not working properly.

Comment: No again when i click the first tab, the div part is not getting changed

Comment: U can itself check one or two times bro, you can identify that, the contents are not changing automatically

Comment: When clicking on the tab, the tabs are changing but the contents inside the tab is not changing automatically. Please help.

Comment: That was because we changed only the <a> tag text value. It will work if you also switch the href attributes of both <a> tags. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVJ46/2/). Please check now.